minio - s3 - CORS policy not well-formed
I set a bucket policy that my specific domain can get the bucket object, now how to set CORS policy in minio - s3? I purchase it from my hosting company and they give me only client web interface so then I try to do it in mc
Here is my cross policy and error message:

Here is my bucket policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-1342-0121-sow-default"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-1342-0121-sow-default/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://bdiral.com/*",
                        "https://www.bdiral.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


i cannot set cross origin policy in minio s3. i purchse it to a hosting company and they give me only web interface console.
error: mc:  Unable to set bucket CORS configuration for myminioaa/s3-1342-0121-sow-default. The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema.
how to solve it

I took your policy, modified it for my bucket name and managed to add it successfully to my S3 bucket. Therefore, there is no particular syntax error. I notice that your error message mentions XML and CORS (CORS uses XML). Therefore, I think your program lies in the CORS configuration, not the Bucket Policy.

sir! when i play any movies to that my domain using this custom bucket policy its say source not found but when i make it totally public its working even i search it to my mc consol to get the cross policy its say no cross configuration found
C:\Program Files\minio>mc cors get myminioaa/s3-2849-13283-bdix-default
No bucket CORS configuration found.

how to set cross policy can you assist me!
